# Реакт приложенрие не загружается после публикации на GH Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Ссылка на проект : [клик](https://nikulio.github.io/office_dashboard/)

Воспользовался стандартным гайдом в терминале "как залить прод на gh pages". Вбиваю `npm run deploy`, ввожу SSH pass, получаю ответ Published, якобы все в порядке. Захожу, а там пустой экран. Ошибок в консоли нет, файлы подтянулись. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD : Роутинг :

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles/main.css";
import "./styles/reset.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import history from "./history";

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import Application from "./Application";
import DashboardComponent from "./DashboardComponent";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Application} />
        </Switch>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Application.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import DashboardComponent from "./DashboardComponent";
import Menu from "./Menu.js";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js";
import "../css/page-content.css";
import Account from "./Account";

class Application extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="page-content">
          <Menu />
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/dashboard/dash"
                component={DashboardComponent}
              />
              <Route exact path="/dashboard/account_info" component={Account} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Application;
```

Comment: Показывайте свой роутинг компонентов, это поможет. Главная работает, что-то в логике рендеринга натворили. Плюс сразу вопрос: используете `redux` и `react-router@4`?

Comment: На GitHub Pages? Роутинг? Надеюсь, там есть режим работы через фрагментную часть URL (`#!/путь` или аналогичный)?

Comment: @Klimenkomud  Да. А в чем проблем с ними? Сейчас перелопачу его и обновлю

Comment: @D-side Не понял что это значит :(

Comment: Ну смотрите, если вы используете клиентский роутинг, а сервер о нём ничего не знает и просто раздаёт статические файлы на указанных местах, на клиенте легко получить URL, который сервер не сможет обслужить при открытии его в дальнейшем. Для таких серверов следует использовать роутинг с помощью фрагмента URL, части что после символа `#`, т. к. она существует только для клиента и в запросе на сервер не участвует. У вас, впрочем, похоже, что проблема не непосредственно эта.

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov роутер 4 и редакс плохо работают. Вы не можете подтянуть компонент из роута, т.к. редакс не видит необходимости  в ре-рендеринге компонента,содержащего ваш роутинг. Правда в таком случае у вас должно было всё плохо работать ещё при разработке, так-что возможно проблема не в этом

Comment: @Klimenkomud дополнил ответ, проверьте пожалуйста

Comment: @D-side звучит сложно :) добавил код с роутингом, проверьте пожалуйста

Comment: Добавьте полный код компонента(вообще полный, с импортами и экспортами, объявлениями классов и т.д.), то, что я вижу, и то, что вы добавили в вопрос - две абсолютно разные вещи, где-то ошибка. Были ошибки при билде?

Comment: @Klimenkomud Добавил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov Внимательно изучите последних 2 ссылки, там есть ответ как справится с вашей проблемой

Answer (score 1):

Вангую, что проблема в роутинге. Если перейти на https://nikulio.github.io/ без office_dashboard, приложение что-то показывает. Без исходников точнее сказать сложно.

Comment: Это да. А что бы вам помогло из исходников?